# Create unprotected executable for program that decrypts itself at run-time dynamically?

Tags: ida, windows, x86, pe, decryption

Say i have Windows executable that looks like normal one, but actually has encrypted segments or blocks of code, and the way it calculates key to decrypt itself at run-time way hard for me.

I'd like to try create a decrypted version of that program by stripping out "self-decryptor part" and exporting program as it was at run-time (under debug). I am not looking for way to find & remove decryption-related code.

Having IDA Pro (or  other tools), how can i re-save executable file at run-time (after program decrypted itself), or i am thinking in completely wrong direction and should not try doing it?

I've read [this answer and question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/packed-pe-file-where-to-start?rq=1) but i am wondering if i really cannot just re-save executable at runtime and try to make it "runnable"? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with a packed/crypted executable it is not possible to just dump the file from memory and make it "runnable". You need to do at least two things:

- Modify the [Entry Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) so that you bypass the execution of the code in the unpacking stub.
- Fix the [import table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Import_Table).

To do these two things, you need to have some basic understanding about the [PE file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). You can find some useful links about the PE file format in this [answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/11478/12897).

If you know what type of crypter/packer is being used on the file, feel free to upload the sample or tell me so I can maybe give you some guidelines on obtaining the payload. You can check this with a tool like [PEid](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) or [ExeInfo](http://exeinfo.atwebpages.com/).